# Javascript can not get property with obj.x

Tags: javascript

I know that getting values of JS object's can be done like this:

```
obj1.x
```

or

```
obj1[x]
```

But in example below `obj1.x` is not working. Why?

```
var txt = "";
var person = {fname:"John", lname:"Doe", age:25};

for (x in person) {
    txt += person[x] + " ";//this is working
    txt += person.x + " ";//this is not working
}
```

This shows that x is name of the property:

```
    for (x in person) {
        txt += x;//output: fname, lname
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj.x` is equivalent to `obj['x']`

While `obj[x]` in your case is equivalent  to `obj['fname']` or `obj['lname']`

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is not correct. The following are not the same:

```
obj1.x
obj[x]
```

In the first syntax, `x` must be the literal property name, so your object really needs to have `x` as property. For example:

```js
var obj = { x: 1 }
console.log(obj.x);
```

In the second syntax, `x` must be a variable, and the targetted property name is the value of that variable. For example:

```js
x = "y";
obj = { y: 1 }
console.log(obj[x]);
```

However, you can also use the second syntax for a literal property name, in which case you quote it, like you would do for other literal strings:

```js
obj = { y: 1 }
console.log(obj["y"]);
```

In fact, it could be any expression, as long as the result is the property name you target.

Answer (score 1):

Here `txt += person.x`  doesn't work because `x` is a dynamic variable not resolved as a key for the `persons` object.So it treats `x` as a key in the `persons` object and since it is not present, it returns undefined. However when you do `person[x]` , `x` is resolved to the corresponding `key` string and you get the result, much like in a for loop to access arrays `array[i]` gives you the value for the array at `index i`

Answer (score 1):

Using square brackets, javascript can resolve dynamic object keys.

```
var txt = "";
var person = {fname:"John", lname:"Doe", age:25};

for (x in person) {
  txt += person[x] + " "; //working
  txt += person.x + " "; // here it tried to resolve "x" not dynamic value of "x" i.e fname/lname
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not access property using `.` operator for dynamic expression in JavaScript.